# Switch tool and change context menu?

Tags: source-engine, garrys-mod

In Garry's Mod, using the `gmod_tool` command (as in `gmod_tool faceposer`) changes the active toolgun, but not the associated context menu. Is there a command I can use to change the active context menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such command built in, but if you have Wiremod installed, it provides a `toolcpanel` command that sets both toolgun and its context menu. You can use it like `bind t "toolcpanel wire_adv"`.

Found the answer in [this thread](http://facepunch.com/showthread.php?t=1232171).

Comment: Does this work for toolguns that aren't part of wiremod?

Comment: Yes, built-in and 3rd-party tools work also. I have set bindings like `bind del "toolcpanel remover"` for variety of tools.